# Error/problem with a changing state in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, axios

I would like to send the id book and the returnDate to the back via Axios. However, it's ok for the id but for the returnDate, the value stays "undefined". 
What can I add/change in my code in order to change the returnDate with the date entered in the input at the end of the code? and so use it in the handleSubmit function.
Thank you.

```
    import { MDBBtn, MDBTableBody, MDBTableHead, MDBTable, MDBModal, MDBModalHeader, MDBModalBody, MDBModalFooter} from "mdbreact";
    import axios from 'axios';

class MyLends extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lends: null,
      returnDate: null,
      modal: false,
      id: '',
      error:'',
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


toggle = () => {
  this.setState({
    modal: !this.state.modal
  });
}

change = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
  });
}

handleSubmit = (id, returnDate) => e => {
  console.log(id, returnDate);
  const { lends } = this.state;
  let newBooks = lends;
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("id",id);
  formData.append("returnDate",returnDate);
  const url = "http://localhost:8888/liste_prets/rendu_pret.php"
  axios.post(url, formData)

  .then(function(response){
    const tmp = lends;
    newBooks = tmp.filter(livre => livre.id !== id);
    alert('Succès : Livre à nouveau marqué comme disponible');
  })

  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
    if (error.response.status === 403){
      console.log(error);
      alert('Echec du rendu');
    }
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      lends: newBooks
    })
  }, 500);


  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      error: '',
    });
  }, 2000);

  e.preventDefault();
}


async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:8888/liste_prets/liste.php";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({lends: data.results.livres, loading: false})
    console.log(data.results.livres);
  }

render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <MDBTable hover>
            <MDBTableHead>
              <tr>
              <th>Titre</th>
              <th>Auteur</th>
              <th>Emprunteur</th>
              <th>Date d'emprunt</th>
              <th></th>
              </tr>
            </MDBTableHead>
            <MDBTableBody>
              {
                this.state.lends.map(livre => (
                  <tr key={livre.id} onChange={this.Change} >
                    <td>{livre.title}</td>
                    <td>{livre.author}</td>
                    <td>{livre.borrower}</td>
                    <td>{livre.borrowDate}</td>
                    <td><MDBBtn onClick={this.toggle} color="dark">Rendu</MDBBtn>
                        <MDBModal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
                          <MDBModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Date de rendu</MDBModalHeader>
                          <MDBModalBody>
                            <input
                              type="date"
                              id="returnDate"
                              placeholder="jj/mm/aa"
                              className="form-control"
                              onChange={this.Change}
                            />
                          </MDBModalBody>
                          <MDBModalFooter>
                            <MDBBtn color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Annuler</MDBBtn>
                            <MDBBtn color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit(livre.id, this.returnDate)}>Enregistrer</MDBBtn>
                          </MDBModalFooter>
                        </MDBModal>


                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              }
            </MDBTableBody>
          </MDBTable>

        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default MyLends;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just setState on `this.change` as you already bind it input's onChange event. And don't forget javascript is **case sensitive**

```
change = e => {
  this.setState({
    returnDate: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

and in your input you might want to lower onChange to `onChange={this.change}`

**Extra;**

You should access to returnDate as; `this.handleSubmit(livre.id, this.state.returnDate)`

Comment: It's ok, Thank you!

Comment: @chiche you might accept it if it resolved your problem